# How to know data changes from api

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I am currently developing an app that consumes an API football score "https://www.api-football.com",  how can I know the change that happens in a match or the list of matches, that's what the good practices that I can use, is possible to use rxjava or something like that in this case or create a service that runs in the background.

Comment: This is a pretty generic question. Since the API doesn't provide you with a way to receive a notification when something changes, you are going to have re-request the data at an interval and see if the results change. Beyond that the details on how all depend on your app and how it was built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when you have your own database/server, you set up realtime notifications or webhooks to receive updates, but in your case you are using a third party api that does not support it.

First obvious solution would be to poll the server in a background server, *however*, if the library is not free, you will easily exhaust your qouta once the number of users increase. Think of 1 user polling a third party server every minute for 24 hours. that easily amounts to 60*24 = 1440 api calls per user per day per url.
Which means that if 1 user is listening to only 1 endpoint for 1 day, he/she will consume 1440 api calls.

To avoid that, you can have your own server that polls the server and notifies the users that subscribed to the data. This way, you will consume a fixed amount of api calls regardless of the amount of users.

Now as for the specific api that you want to use, Leagues, Players and rest of the data mostly stay same. What you want to listen to is events from a game. As per their documentation, events are updated every minute but these events are only limited to a fixture. Transfers are updated once a day as per their documentation. To save up usage, your user can send a request to your server to subscribe to a fixture, the server checks every minute if there are fixtures that are being subscribed by users and if any fixture has subscriber count > 0 it will poll the server for updated data. This will reduce your api calls.

Pro Plan worth 19$ will give you 7500 requests. Since each user will use 1440 requests per day, so you can only support 40-50 users before you reach limit. For 500 users it will cost you 30$. And 40$ will get you 100 users worth of limit. 
That is if you decide to poll directly from client.

Another point to consider is that for small number of users, running a server task every minute would be more expensive than polling the server from client app. But as the user count increases, server will become cheaper compared to other option.

**TL;DR**: Build a server that polls the third party server in intervals only if there are users that subscribe to data.

Comment: Thank you for answer i  think  it will  help me.